# Understanding inline onclick event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, inline

I'v created a link from a span for a couple reasons.

Instead of:

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>
```

My links in some places look like this:

```
 <span class="link" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.com/'">link</span>
```

I want to control a Jquery UI accordion that i would normally would get to work like this:

```
<a href="#" data-panel="0" class="accordion">open accorion</a>
```

But how to get this to work with inline onclick?

`<span class="link" onclick="open data-panel0">open accorion</span>`   ????

I don't have experience with onclick events, so any suggestion is appreciated
Thanks for all the help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really concentrate your efforts on inline click events, as they're widely regarded as bad practice. As you're using jquery, you can attach your click events on document ready, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").click(function () {
        //replace yourAccordion with the class of your actual accordion.
        $(".yourAccordion").slideDown();
    });
});
```